# Averaging column values in rows

Tags: java, mysql, birt

I am trying to make a query for a chart in BIRT. I have a table similar to the following:

```
id   score_1   score_2   score_3
1     80.5       81.2      81.3
2     90.1       88.9      87.1
3     85.6       87.5      84.8
```

What I need to do is get the average of each score column and output them in rows like this:

```
   score    average
     1       85.4
     2       85.87
     3       84.4
```

Been trying for a while and short of a chain of queries in UNION, is there a more efficient way to go about this? Note that the table is also joined to other tables used for filtering.

Comment: Do you need the sql query to get the average of 3 columns?

Comment: Yes, this will be used by a chart as the datasource.

Comment: Are there a fixed number of scores?  So you will always have 3 (or 5 or whatever) rows?  If not consistent is there max number of rows that will not be exceeded (i.e. never more then Score_9)

Answer (score 0):

Got it. You want the output in Rows. As of now, there does not seem to be a readily available `TRANSPOSE` function in `MySQL`. The best I can think of is this, which I believe you have already tried.

```
SELECT score_id, score_avg 
FROM (
  SELECT '1' as score_id, avg(score_1) as score_avg FROM scores
  UNION
  SELECT '2' as score_id, avg(score_2) as score_avg FROM scores
  UNION
  SELECT '3' as score_id, avg(score_3) as score_avg FROM scores
  ) as transpose_table;
```

[SQL Fiddle Link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29a6d/23/0)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't output them as columns like that, it displays incorrectly for the BIRT chart that will use it.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT (score_1 + score_2 + score_3)/3 as AVERAGE
FROM scores;
```

You can use union

```
SELECT AVG(score_1)FROM scores
UNION
select AVG(score_2) FROM scores
UNION
select AVG(score_3) FROM scores
```

Comment: That just averages the scores per id, I need to average per score.

Comment: I have already mentioned that I was trying to avoid chaining select statements with UNION since there are many other tables joined to the table as well as parameters for filtering.

Comment: What you wish to achieve is called PIVOT in sqlserver. But in MySql its a bit more difficult. You can check the following link http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Programming:MySQL/Pivot_table